# Why is yarn create react-app ./ not working

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg-v2

```
PS C:\Users\Lewis Wachira\OneDrive\Desktop\Snack Shark Restaurant> cd clientPS C:\Users\Lewis Wachira\OneDrive\Desktop\Snack Shark Restaurant\client> yarn create react-app ./yarn create v1.22.19[1/4] Resolving packages...[2/4] Fetching packages...[3/4] Linking dependencies...[4/4] Building fresh packages...
```

```
success Installed "create-react-app@5.0.1" with binaries:create-react-app'C:\Users\Lewis' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.error Command failed.Exit code: 1Command: C:\Users\Lewis Wachira\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin\create-react-appArguments: ./Directory: C:\Users\Lewis Wachira\OneDrive\Desktop\Snack Shark Restaurant\clientOutput:
```

```
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/create for documentation about this command.
```

I'm trying to create a react app in my client folder but I'm getting an error. The first command I ran was:

1. cd client

Then I ran

2. yarn create react-app ./`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should instead run

```
yarn create react-app .
```

If you can't do it with yarn, I'll suggest you to try with npx or npm, like this:

```
npx create-react-app .
```

or

```
npm init react-app .
```

That `.` specifies the location for the react app to be initialized.

Comment: I used (npx create-react-app . ) and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: @LewisWachira appreciate it!  If I helped you, you may set my answer to accepted so other people know that! You can do it by pressing the check under the top/bottom vote button <3